# Uso da palavra ecossistema em TI

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, significado-em-contexto

Tenho visto e ouvido muita gente de TI usando a palavra "ecossistema" para se referir a um conjunto de sistemas, processos etc.
Eu sou de TI não faz muito tempo mas acho muuuito estranho o uso dessa palavra nesse contexto.
Para mim, essa palavra se refere ao sistema que inclui os seres vivos, o ambiente, etc.

Alguém pode me dizer se o uso dessa palavra estaria correto nesse contexto e eu não estou sabendo?

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o uso recorrente de ecossistema no contexto das TI, estará relacionado com o uso originalmente na língua inglesa, algo comum nesta área do conhecimento.

O Ciberdúvidas explica um pouco mais em detalhe:

- https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-de-ecossistema/33975

Outro exemplo muito em voga é "nuvem" (*cloud*).

Answer (score 1):

Sim, está correto - ou pelo menos é de uso corrente.

O termo "ecossistema" nesse caso normalmente denota uma de duas coisas:

1. um conjunto de elementos diversos (programas, aplicativos, serviços, aparelhos, etc.) que interagem de maneira significativa entre si ou até são interdependentes;
2. um conjunto de elementos de um dado tipo, via de regra diverso e abrangente, criado, e.g., de maneira orgânica por meio de contribuição de terceiros.

O exemplo mais prominente de ecossistema é provavelmente o construído pela Apple, mas outras empresas, como Google e Microsoft também construíram os seus, com maior ou menor sucesso. Seus ecossistemas, no sentido (1) acima, são constituídos especialmente por:

- smartphones, tablets, notebooks, TVs, etc.
- seus sistemas operacionais
- aplicativos/programas
- serviços (email, pagamentos, streaming, etc.)
- aparelhos compatíveis e acessórios (autofalantes, relógios, etc.)

enquanto o conjunto de aplicativos disponíveis para uma dada plataforma (e.g., Play Store, App Store) constitui um ecossistema no sentido (2) acima.

Outro exemplo de ecossistema na acepção (1) é dado na Techopedia, que [define](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31255/hadoop-ecosystem) o ecossistema do Hadoop (uma estrutura, *framework*, para grandes quantidades de dados) como:

> os diversos componentes da biblioteca de programas, assim como os acessórios e ferramentas [...]

Note que uma questão similar existe no SuperUser: [What is ecosystem in IT world?](https://superuser.com/questions/553784/what-is-ecosystem-in-it-world).

Comment: Você deu uma explicação sobre o uso dessa palavra, mas para língua portuguesa o uso dela está correto mesmo para esse fim? Postei essa pergunta porque vejo muita gente em TI falando inglês e português errado. Então queria a opinião de uma pessoa que entendesse muito bem da língua portuguesa para dar uma opinião.

Comment: @EvertonSolon Sim, não sou filólogo, nem linguista, apenas fiz uma descrição do significado da palavra nesse contexto tal como vejo sendo usada. Ao contrário de termos mais antigos, como *smartphone* ou *mouse*, ela não está ainda dicionarizada: então, se estar dicionarizado for teu critério de correção, está errado - e pode, no máximo, ser tomado como uma analogia.

Comment: Benvindo aos 5000! :)

Comment: @ANeves Hehehe... obrigado.